# Multi-Asset Heston Model

Tags: heston

How does one best define the correlation structure in a Multivariate Heston Setup? (i.e. Correlations between the Wiener processes of the Stocks / their Variance Processes)

Comment: Have a look at this paper and references therein: https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=2729475